# Android plugin for Eclipse gets stuck at application name

Tags: android, eclipse

When using the Eclipse plugin, I get stuck at this step...
[image]

What's going on..? I *did* enter a name.

Comment: If you select a Build SDK does it have the same issue?

Comment: Have you ever been able to create a Android project?  If not, I'm wondering if you've downloaded the SDK's (in Eclipse...  Window -> Android SDK Manager).

Comment: You need to have one or more SDK Platforms installed as well.  Each of these has an API Level and Android version (e.g., Android 4.1 (API 16).  Any of these installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Build SDK field is blank, this indicates you have installed part of the SDK, but none of the SDK Platforms. You need to have one or more SDK Platforms installed as well. Each of these has an API Level and Android version (e.g., Android 4.1 (API 16).

In Eclipse, go to Window -> Android SDK Manager.  Select one or more SDK Platforms to install.  As an example, the SDK Manager on my system shows shows several SDK Platforms are installed.  Here's a partial view:

[image]

Note the various versions of the SDK Platform have a status of "Installed"